# How to filter ID from Realm

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to filter out a id from Realm object like this:

```
let itemsInCart = realm.objects("Cart").filtered("id = " + itemId);
```

My Cart schema is as follows:

```
export const CART_SCHEMA = "Cart";
export const CartSchema = {
  name: CART_SCHEMA,
  primaryKey: "id",
  properties: {
    id: "string",
    quantity: "int",
    productName: "string",
    productImage: "string"
  }
};
```

I want to check whether the id exists or not in my Cart object but whenever I try to filter out the id it gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to filter object by ID in Realm

```
let itemsInCart = realm.objects("Cart").filtered("id == $0", itemId);
```